# C# Copy-paste multiple times not working

Tags: c#

In Visual C#, I'm trying to take text from multiple textboxes (one at a time) and paste them into Notepad. I do this by copying to the clipboard, alt-tabbing, and then pasting into notepad...then again for the other textboxes. This code represents this idea:

```
subBox1.SelectAll();
subBox1.Copy();
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");    // alt+tab
SendKeys.Send("^v");        // paste
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");     // tab

subBox2.SelectAll();
subBox2.Copy();
SendKeys.Send("^v");
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

subBox3.SelectAll();
subBox3.Copy();
SendKeys.Send("^v");
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

As you can see, this copies and pastes from three textboxes (named subBox1, 2, and 3). But, for some reason, only the last textbox's contents are getting copied over. This also happens if I comment out the third box...in that case, only the second textbox's content gets copied over. I've tried using the SelectAll() and Copy() as you see here, as well as the Clipboard class. Both have the same issue.

For example, if the textbox contents are "asdf", "qwer", and "zxcv" respectively, all I see is "zxcv" three times.

Any idea why this is happening? I've been stuck on this for about an hour now and have no idea what's going on.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendKeys doesn't wait for the other application to process the keys you send, so by the time notepad gets around to processing your keypresses, your program has already copied `subBox3`'s text over the top of the other texts.

You need to use [SendWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) instead.

As well, instead of sending Alt+Tab, you could use something like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// ... 

SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad"));
```

Comment: Hmm, now the alt-tab doesn't go. I tried keeping the alt-tab as just "Send" as well. Any idea why that doesn't work as it should?

Comment: Not sure about using SendKeys for alt-tab. Apparently there's no built-in method to switch to another app. I would use FindWindow + SetForegroundWindow native calls.

Comment: Edited. Alt-tab is pretty unreliable - you're assuming notepad is the next app in the list. SetForegroundWindow is a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SendMessage for more accurate results. To use SendMessage, you first need a valid window handle to the text area of Notepad. This can be done in a variety of ways, but I prefer just using my simple child lookup function.

You will need the following namespace imports and PInvoke declarations:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

//pinvoke
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hParent, delChildWndProc callback, IntPtr lpParam);
//delegate callback for EnumChildWindows:
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private delegate bool delChildWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
```

Now, onto the child window lookup. Basically works similar to FindWindowEx, but I wanted to write my own, and it retrieves multiple windows which can be nice. It uses the following wrapper class to describe information between calls:

```
private class WindowLookup
{
    public string LookupName { get; private set; }
    public List<IntPtr> MatchedChildren { get; private set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
    public int MaxDepth { get; set; }

    public WindowLookup(string lookup, int maxdepth)
    {
        this.MatchedChildren = new List<IntPtr>();
        this.LookupName = lookup;
        this.MaxDepth = maxdepth;
        if (this.MaxDepth > 0)
            this.MaxDepth++; //account for the depth past the parent control.
        this.Depth = 0;
    }
}
```

And then the following functions do all the work:

```
private static List<IntPtr> FindAllWindows(IntPtr hParent, string className, int maxdepth = 0)
{
    var lookup = new WindowLookup(className, maxdepth);
    var gcAlloc = GCHandle.Alloc(lookup);
    try
    {
        LookupChildProc(hParent, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcAlloc));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (gcAlloc.IsAllocated)
            gcAlloc.Free();
    }
    return lookup.MatchedChildren;
}

private static bool LookupChildProc(IntPtr hChild, IntPtr lParam)
{
    var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(lParam);
    WindowLookup lookup = null;
    if (handle.IsAllocated && (lookup = handle.Target as WindowLookup) != null)
    {
        if (lookup.Depth < lookup.MaxDepth || lookup.MaxDepth == 0)
        {
            lookup.Depth++;
            var builder = new StringBuilder(256);
            if (GetClassName(hChild, builder, builder.Capacity) && builder.ToString().ToLower() == lookup.LookupName.ToLower())
                lookup.MatchedChildren.Add(hChild);
            EnumChildWindows(hChild, LookupChildProc, lParam);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You don't need to worry about the implementation of these functions too much, they'll work as-is. The key thing is that using these functions, you can find the handle to `notepad`'s `Edit` window (the text area you type in) very easily.

```
var notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
if (notepads.Length > 0)
{
    foreach(var notepad in notepads) //iterate through all the running notepad processes. Of course, you can filter this by processId or whatever.
    {
        foreach(var edit in FindAllWindows(notepad.MainWindowHandle, "Edit"))
        {
            //next part of the code will go here, read on.
        }

    }
}
```

Now, where I left the code was in the middle of a loop through the "Edit" windows of each notepad process running at the time. Now that we have a valid window handle, we can use SendMessage to send stuff to it. In particular, appending text. I wrote the following function to handle appending text to a remote control:

```
private static void AppendWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text)
{
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        //for your reference, 0x0E (WM_GETTEXTLENGTH), 0xB1 (EM_SETSEL), 0xC2 (EM_REPLACESEL)
        int len = SendMessage(hWnd, 0x000E, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32();
        var unmanaged = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(text);
        SendMessage(hWnd, 0x00B1, new IntPtr(len), new IntPtr(len));
        SendMessage(hWnd, 0x00C2, IntPtr.Zero, unmanaged);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanaged);
    }
}
```

Now that we have our AppendWindowText function, you can add a function call to it in the nested loop above (where I put the comment):

```
AppendWindowText(edit, "Some text here");
```

And there you have it. It's a bit of a wordy response, but in the end this method is far more reliable than using SendKeys and focusing the window etc. You never need to lose focus of your own application.

If you have any questions, feel free to comment and I'll answer as best I can.

Cheers,
J

EDIT: Some references:

[SendMessage function (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[EnumChildWindows function (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Appending text using SendMessage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109550)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your time. Unfortunately this is a bit overwhelming. This is my first day using Visual C# as well as any Windows API type stuff. I just started what I thought was a pretty simple project to get my feet wet. But...with all of the issues with setting window focus, I think I'm a bit over my head for now.

Comment: That's fair enough, if you've never dealt with Win32 forms programming in C++, SendMessage can be quite a handful. One alternative you can take is to use `AppActivate` to set the focus window, then do your pasting. If you want, I can write you a single-use function using the above code that you can call simply `AppendTextToNotepad(text)`, so you can learn the other code at your leisure, but still have a working, reliable, application.

Comment: That'd be great, if it's easy to implement! I think at this point I'm also unsure where to stick code that I don't fully understand yet, haha. Please let me know where it goes.

Thanks again!

Comment: If only SO had a private messaging system. I'll link a pastie link in the comments when I'm finished work.

Comment: @PlanetLotus Here's a wrapper class I wrote: http://pastie.org/private/tjocpuoy8ocqvfqenhravw now, in Visual Studio go `Project >> Add Class` use `MessageWrapper` as the class name. Once VS generates the document, delete everything between `namespace XXXXXX {` and the final closing brace. Then paste in the code I linked. You should end up with something like: http://pastie.org/private/zwqbwgrnhqfv712k5waavg.

Comment: Next, go back to your main class and add the following function: http://pastie.org/4282164. That's all the hard work done. Now, where you had your original code, simply put `AppendProcessText("notepad", subBox1.Text);`...etc

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! Works like a charm (anything I don't understand is indistinguishable from magic, right? hehe). Thanks a ton!